# Keep locations in drupal

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have created a form where customers select two fields for a transportation. From `origin` to `destination`. My list of geographical locations could be close to 5,000 records. What is the best way to keep this location in the database? Taxonomy or store as a list for selection on each field?

Any recommendation is more than welcome. I'd need to store something like this:

El Salvador SVCSC   Cara Sucia  Cara Sucia, SV  SVCSC|Cara Sucia, SV

El Salvador SVCNG   Chalatenango    Chalatenango, SV    SVCNG|Chalatenango, SV

An important point is that I need users to select this with autocomplete like any airline website does (Kayak, Hipmunk, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a content type Locations

and add the following as form fields
1.cities
2.states(Provinces)
3.countries

Use two modules

1. [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference)

   Use a field entity reference in your custom form for origin and destination with content type locations
2. [Tokens](https://drupal.org/project/token)  3. [Auto nodetitle](https://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle)
   By installing the tokens and auto node title you can set the title for locations as per your needs
   like [field:cities]|[field:province]|[field:country] in the edit link of content type locations

the title u set for the content type will be used in the origin and destination field . You can set your field as autocomplete as well as follows:

```
function module_name_menu() {  
  $items['location/autocomplete'] = array(
    'page callback' => '_module_name_autocomplete',
    'access arguments' => array('access location autocomplete'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return $items;
}


function module_name_form() {
  $form = array();

  $form['origin'] = array(
    '#title' => t('origin'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'location/autocomplete',
   );

  $form['destination'] = array(
    '#title' => t('destination'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'location/autocomplete',
   );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Save',
  );

  return $form;
}

function _module_name_autocomplete($string) {
  $matches = array();


  $query = db_select('locations', 'loc');
     ->fields('loc', array('title'))
    ->condition('c.title', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->range(0, 10)
    ->execute();

  // add matches to $matches  
  foreach ($return as $row) {
    $matches[$row->title] = check_plain($row->title);
  }

  // return for JS
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where do I put this piece of code? Do I need to create a module with it? or just saving it to an specific folder with an specific extension?

Comment: create a custom module for this piece of code.In the sites/all/modules/ you should create a custom folder e.g located_dropdown

Comment: Inside the located_drop down create a located_dropdown.info file .you can check drupal.org on how to write .info file and then create located_dropdown.module and inside it enter the above piece of code